# Spring MVC - OSGi integration without Spring-DM

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, osgi

Is it possible to integrate Spring MVC with OSGi HTTP Services "without" Spring-DM?

Edit: To be clear, what I mean is that is it possible to initialize the Spring container manually and register the appropriate servlets via the HTTP service?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, in your OSGi bundle `Activator` ([implement `BundleActivator`](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.html)) you can create the Spring context manually. There are a [bunch of ways to do that](https://github.com/rahulaga/hello-spring). Then you will have the Spring `ApplicationContext` and the OSGi `BundleContext` and you can do whatever you need to do.